# UITextView responding to touches, but keyboard doesn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't comprehend it. I have a uitextview which animates upward when it begins editing to make room for the keyboard. I tap the uitextview and registers that it has begun editing and it animates up but the keyboard doesn't appear. This has never happened before and I've tested the app hundreds of times. I even have the textview become first responder upon building the view and the keyboard still doesn't show.

I have the .m file and .h file as  so that is not the issue..

Here is the set up code:

```
self.addDescriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 470, 320, 100)];
[self.addDescriptionTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWith8BitRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.5]];
[self.addDescriptionTextView setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.addDescriptionTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16]];
[self.addDescriptionTextView setDelegate:self];

self.addDescriptionTextView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10;
[self.addDescriptionTextView.layoutManager textContainerChangedGeometry:self.addDescriptionTextView.textContainer];

[confirmView addSubview:self.addDescriptionTextView];
```

Comment: What version of iOS? Which device?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on my iOS device and the keyboard came up,

Heres the viewDidLoad Code I ran,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.addDescriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 470, 320, 100)];
self.addDescriptionTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.addDescriptionTextView setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.addDescriptionTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16]];
[self.addDescriptionTextView setDelegate:self];

self.addDescriptionTextView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10;
[self.addDescriptionTextView.layoutManager textContainerChangedGeometry:self.addDescriptionTextView.textContainer];

self.addDescriptionTextView.editable = YES;

[self.view addSubview:self.addDescriptionTextView];
}
```

Try adding the UIView.editable line but it should be set to yes automatically.

It might have something to do with confirmView?

Also try changing the UIColor Background colour line I was getting errors with your one.

Edit: After running on iPhone4s your problem is the position you initiate the UIView (to see try changing the 470 to 0 in the CGRect to see the bug)

Comment: If it helps my device is an iPhone5s with latest ios

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm running it on iPhone5s with latest ios as well.. again, it's never happened before so I'm completely baffled.

Comment: And do you see the textView when you run it?

Comment: You aren't running on iOS 8 are you? I've noticed this behavior with the betas.